# Safari - http ajax request (to a local device without ssl) inside a https site

Tags: ajax, http, ssl, https, safari

Has anyone an idea, how to ajax request a "local" http address (it is a local hardware device without ssl) inside a https site in Safari or any other browser on an iOS Device?

Thanks for any hint!

Calling http inside a https site gets blocked by browsers. even a local ip, sadly.

Some tips are a pfx file. But a pfx file can no longer be installed on an ios device, since settings->common->certificate trust settings has no longer setting for it. There is only one line "Version" and one more "Trust Asset-Version" - no more settings are available anymore...